# limit edit text in android with decimal

Tags: android

I have a question about limit number in editText. I want to user can enter only number from 1-70. When user want to put 70.01 or more I want to not allowed them.with only two decimal allowed.total length is 5 character including point.

i am able to limit before & after decimal. & also limit the 70 but user can able to enter 70.99(don't know why) in edit text that i want to block. my validation work when user enter 71 or more

this is constructor i im using in fragment

```
     txtno.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {new DecimalDigitsInputFilter(Integer.parseInt(getString(R.string.length)),2,txtno)});
```

this is for after & before decimal

```
@Override
public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end,Spanned dest,    int dstart, int dend) {

    mTextView.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance(true,true));
    String etText = mTextView.getText().toString();
    String temp = mTextView.getText() + source.toString();
    if (temp.equals(".")) {

        return "0.";
    } else if (temp.toString().indexOf(".") == -1) {

        // no decimal point placed yet
        if (temp.length() > mMyint) {

            return "";
        }
    } else {

        int dotPosition;
        int cursorPositon = mTextView.getSelectionStart();

        if (etText.indexOf(".") == -1) {

            dotPosition = temp.indexOf(".");
        } else {

            dotPosition = etText.indexOf(".");
        }
        if (cursorPositon <= dotPosition) {

            String beforeDot = etText.substring(0, dotPosition);
            if (beforeDot.length() < mMyint) {

                    return source;
            } else {

                if (source.toString().equalsIgnoreCase(".")) {

                    return source;
                    } else {

                    return "";
                    }
            }
        } else {

            temp = temp.substring(temp.indexOf(".") + 1);
            if (temp.length() > mMydec) {

                return "";
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

& this is textWatcher for limit 70

```
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    try{

        if(Integer.parseInt(s.toString())>70){

            s.replace(0, s.length(), s.toString());
        }
    }catch(Exception e){}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is that you try to parse int - you need to parse double.

Comment: Thanks dear.. i waste my 5 hour for this silly mistake.